# Building Single Page Application without doing any Server Side Development

Tags: node.js, javascript

I am new to any JS framework and hence I am planning to build a SPA without using any Server Side Development using Ebmer.js. Since everything need to be done at the client side, can it be done without using node.Js which does provide some server side functionality ?

Basically I would like to build a login page functionality so that user can login only when they have provided correct credentials.

Comment: The question is, log in to what? Without a server, there's nothing to log in to

Comment: Without server how would you even route?

Comment: @ShankhoneerChakrovarty You can route without a server (SPA)

Comment: @rocky you cannot create a login without a server, because you have nothing to log into. If you want to _fake_ a login, it will easily be hackable.

Comment: @Secret - no it won't, there won't be anything to hack, there's no point in hacking ones own browser ?

Comment: So, if I am using node.js , can I say that I haven't done any server side development ?

Comment: @Secret ah! you mean no node server but there will be still apache or nginx. Got it!

Comment: actually, most social sign-ins don't require any server-side execution, so you can login in JS only (plus a static html file).

Answer (score 0):

To build a SPA, you can go through different framework like [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) which are AJAX based completely and needs a server. To simulate a server and to handle AJAX request you need to host a local server. Sencha has provided [Sencha CMD 5.x](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/) which you can install in any system (Windows, MAC, Linux). After installing this software you just have to browse to the folder which you want to deploy on the server. 
[image: Target folder to get deployed on server].

Open Command prompt or terminal,and type the command `sencha web start`.
[image: Command prompt with sencha command]

After this you can access your application through a local server hosted on port:**1841**.
You will get an access to your file system as shown below.

[image: Accessing the SPA using local server]

And the result is like

[image: SPA Demo]